# How do I use a dynamic shared library in a C++ xcode project?

Tags: c++, xcode, dylib

I have created a new project in XCode (using the template "STL C++ library"), and have made a little test function `void hello();` that prints to the console.

It compiles fine, and I am able to export a dylib file.

What I can't figure out is how to create a project that then links to this file and can call the `hello()` method.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Alex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create another Xcode project, such as an application project. In your example you could create a command-line tool project that uses C++.

After creating the project add the dylib to the target's Link Binary with Libraries build phase. In Xcode 4, select the project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select the target from the target list on the left side of the project editor. Click the Build Phases button at the top of the editor. Click the disclosure triangle next to the Link Binary with Libraries build phase. Click the + button to add your library.

When you finish adding the dylib to your project, include the header file for your library in your code, and you should be able to call the hello() function. You may also need to add a search path to your library to the Library Search Paths build setting to use your library.

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to solve the problem (I actually made a new target in the same project to do the same thing, for convenience), but this is a good answer for anyone who is still unsure.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. In Windows (for example) I can use LoadLibrary to actually select/load a library at runtime, then I can ask for the addresses of various functions that I want to call. What's described above seems more about using "shared" libraries so that each executable doesn't have to statically link in library code.

Comment: @David Read the title of the question again. It mentions using dynamic shared libraries so you shouldn't be surprised that my answer covers using dynamic shared libraries.

Comment: Yeah sorry --- once I saw 'dynamic', I missed 'shared'. Not sure of the purpose of the term dynamic in front of 'shared' and I normally think of these examples as shared.   I don't think I've ever seen a dynamic static library! In any case, I came across this answer while trying to figure out how to explicitly load an OSX shared library at runtime (i.e. dynamically :-) and find the address of needed functions, from C++. I have since figured it out.